# CSS not showing as same as local on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

Here's what I did already before thinking this is a duplicate.

1. I let heroku do the rake assets:precompile
2. I did it locally, added it to git and pushed

None of these worked? I am thinking maybe Heroku somehow cached the assets which doesn't make sense to me but I have no other ideas at this point. Is this cache idea really possible on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Heroku doesn't cache any assets.

Try to run the following:

```
rm -rf public/cache
git commit -am "Removing cache files"
git push heroku master
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
rm -rf public/cache
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add public/cache
git commit -am "Updated Compiled assets"
git push heroku master
```

You've probably already read [Rails Asset Pipeline on Heroku Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline), if not check it out.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have indeed read that document. About public/cache, there is no such file/folder in the project. this is really weird. I am wondering if twitter-bootstrap-rails app is clashing with some of my css

Comment: That's weird. I have an app deployed on Heroku with Twitter-Bootstrap-Rails and if I remember correctly it went smooth for me. Have you added all your css to git (app/stylesheets/*) ? The only tweak I did was to set config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false in config/application.rb to prevent rails to fail during the assets compilation(not really related to your issue though...).

Comment: At this point I am just manually overriding bootstrap_and_overrides.less file to make sure what I need happens